# "Keyset does not exist" error on Azure worker role

Tags: c#, azure, x509certificate

I have a worker role which uses the Third party WCF services, the developers of WCF services told me to add two certificates on my Azure Trusted Root store, for authentication.

When I am trying to add the same via certificates tab in roles --> properties, it is not allowed.

So I come to a solution, where I write a code in console application along with these two certificates (.cer files). When the worker role executes, it adds these certificates on desired storename i.e. LocalMachine--> TrustedRoot.

However still my application is throwing error saying "Keyset does not exist"

I have checked through RDP, and found that the cer files are already installed on this location.

Also, I am trying to find the Private Key, but unable to do so, I think this is because these are ".cer" files.

Comment: Did the below answer help you, Anurag?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your files are `.cer` which do not store private key. One of these certificates (leaf, or authentication certificate) must be in a PFX. Commonly they have `.pfx` or `.p12` extension.